# Can't Get "lsdvd" To Work On Remastered Live CD's

Tags: livecd, dvd, ram

I have attempted to make Tiny Core Linux, Archboot (didn't get very far), and SliTaz remastered live CD's with **lsdvd** included, in order to create a lightweight transcoding solution that allows as much of the processing to be on the transcoding as I can manage.  Additionally, I opted for these RAM distributions so that I would be able to swap the live CD's out for a DVD without problems.

I have two Virtual Machines set up, one for Tiny Core Linux and the other for SliTaz.  Within the respective operating systems, **lsdvd** seems to work just fine (I installed **libdvdcss** and **libdvdread** on both).

On each, I remastered live CD's so that all three of these packages are installed, and they both seem to behave in a similar way.  That is, although they work on the installed OS's, they bring up similar errors when in a live CD environment.

Here is the the error output for each (this occurs after the version of **libdvdcss**  and before the DVD Title Table are displayed):

**Tiny Core Linux:**

```
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 100301
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 100301
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 4096128
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 4096128
```

**SliTaz:**

```
hdc: command error: status=0x41 { DriveReady Error }
hdc: command error: status=0x50 { LastFailedSense=0x05}
hdc: possibly failed opcode: 0xa0
```

What interests me is that the problem seems to be distribution-independant.  Is there something that I have on my installed VM's that I should be including in order to mitigate this error?  In researching Google, I found that setting a region might help, but I am unsure how I would go about doing that in a portable way.

If there is a simpler way to go about what I am trying to make than how I am making it, I would be grateful if you could let me in on it!  Learning the remastering processes for these different systems is intuitive, but it does take some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with VirtualBox's "Passthrough" feature for the Host IDE Disc Drive.  Without it, **lsdvd** cannot fully function.